Youtube not getting uninstalled from the Programs and features tab windows 11
Youtube not getting uninstalled from the Programs and features tab windows 11. I have tried to uninstall the youtube many times still nothing happens. If i click the uninstall button nothing happens.
Preview of Youtube in Programs and features tab
I need to uninstall youtube completely from my PC.
